# SuperCSV with null delimiter

Tags: supercsv

I'm creating a file that isn't really a csv file, but SuperCSV can help me to make the creation of this file easier. The structure of the file uses different lengths for each line, following a layout that don't separate the different information. So, to know which information has in one line you need look at the first 2 characters (the name of the register), count the characters and extract it by size.

I've configured SuperCSV to use empty delimiter, however, the created file is using a space where it should have nothing.

```
public class TarefaGerarArquivoRegistrosFiscais implements ITarefa {

    private static final CsvPreference FORMATO_ANEXO_IV = new CsvPreference.Builder('"', '\0' , "\r\n").build();

    public void processar() {
        try {
            writer = new CsvListWriter(getFileWriter(), FORMATO_ANEXO_IV);
            writer.write(geradorRegistroU1.gerar());
        } finally {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing something wrong? '\0' is the correct code for a null char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not what you want to hear, but I wouldn't recommend using Super CSV for this (and I'm a committer!). Its sole purpose is to deal with delimited files - and you're not using delimiters.

You could misuse Super CSV by creating a wrapper object (containing your List) whose `toString()` method simply concatenates all of the values together, then passing that single object to `writer.write()`, but it's an awful hack.

I'd recommend either finding another library more suited to your problem, or writing your own solution.